# How to prevent characters entered in the middle of a textarea erasing characters due to max length

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

When implementing a maxlength style directive in AngualrJS is is possible to type a character into the middle of the textbox - this causes the directive to fire and the total string is truncated to the max length - however, because the new character is in the middle the character lost is not the one just typed.

```
myAppModule.directive('myMaxlength', ['$compile', '$log', function($compile, $log) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            attrs.$set("ngTrim", "false");
            var maxlength = parseInt(attrs.myMaxlength, 10);
            ctrl.$parsers.push(function (value) {
                $log.info("In parser function value = [" + value + "].");
                if (value.length > maxlength)
                {
                    $log.info("The value [" + value + "] is too long!");
                    value = value.substr(0, maxlength);
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(value);
                    ctrl.$render();
                    $log.info("The value is now truncated as [" + value + "].");
                }
                return value;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

This fiddle (not mine) shows such a directive in use:

http://jsfiddle.net/ksevksev/J7MJF/

To reproduce, just type a letter in the middle and see the output model altered. The desired behaviour here is that the user would be prevented from typing additional characters into the text area if the content is already at the maxlength - i.e. the directive should behave the way the MaxLength attribute works in Firefox/Chrome

Is there a way of hooking up the AngularJS directive such that we can detect if the character has been added at the end or in the middle and truncatre accordingly? I'm not sure how to access the original value of the model inside the directive, but that would at least enable some comparisons

(I know that using the default HTML MaxLength attribute are available in Chrome and Firexfox which would render this directive useless - but I need to support IE7 where the MaxLength isn't implemented.)

Comment: Can you explain how you want it to behave?

Comment: @DTing Updated to be clear on desired behaviour